# Kafka SFTP Source Connector stops if CSV file is big ( 50 MB to 500 MB) and needs restart

Tags: csv, apache-kafka, sftp, apache-kafka-connect

While using stand alone set up, if the input CSV file is bigger, anywhere from 50MB and above, the Kafka connector to read CSV stops abruptly. Restarting the Kafka connector  helps to finish processing but adds some duplicate messages.
Is there any threshold to the file size to read or any memory, CPU requirements to process CSV files upto 500MB size?

Comment: Have you tried adding more heap space? Are you monitoring any CPU or memory usage?

Comment: Yes, I had tried increasing heap upto 6GB. The CPU utilisation at that time shows very high, around 150% and memory utilisation is around 80%. Does increasing CPU cores would help?

Comment: It's possible, but it's also possible that kafka connect may not be the best option, assuming you're limited to sftp

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand what you meant by limited to SFTP, do you mean Kafka connector may not be the best option for processing big CSV files from SFTP?  and probably I should import CSV in a different way?

Comment: That's right. For example, SFTP is limited to a single connection for file reading. If you used S3/HDFS, for example, then alternative big data processing tools such as Spark can read csv files in parallel from there and write to Kafka. Or you could use a simple RDBMS table rather than CSV files

Answer (score 0):

The default value for behavior.on.error is FAIL.
According to the docs:

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/sftp/current/source-connector/license_config.html#schema-and-schema-generation

this way the connector stops whenever an error occurs.
Set the value to LOG, so that possible errors are logged and processing jumps to the next file.
You should be able to understand the reason for the failure.

Take a look at the following post on OpenCsv behaviour on failures:

[Reading large CSV files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820529/reading-large-csv-files-in-java)

You might also activate connector logs. Take a look at the docs:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/logging.html#log4j-properties-file

Comment: By increasing CPU and memory, I was able to process bigger files (~ 70 MB) without any errors. But when the resources were less , the connector stops even when there are no errors in logs with 'LOG' setting.

Comment: Try to increase logging level to TRACE. You could also generate a heap dump of the worker process setting the startup parameter -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError or using the command: "jcmd <pid> GC.heap_dump <file-path>" in order to understand the reason for the block.